# How to say something sponsors another

Tags: possessives

If book A is sponsored by entity B, how can I say:

> . . . in the upcoming B **'s** sponsored book A .
>   . .

or

> . . . in the upcoming B sponsored book A . .
>   .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The upcoming B's sponsored book A" would be understood as "the upcoming B's book A"; the same is true for the second phrase you wrote.

I would write the sentence as

> The upcoming book A, sponsored by B, […].
>   The upcoming B-sponsored book A […].

My personal preference is for the first of these sentences.

Comment: +1:  "sponsored by" as a parenthetical element sounds much better than the others.

Answer (score 3):

The possessive is wrong, unless the sponsor is also the author, in which case you probably don't call it a sponsor anyway. So, I would recommend the second sentence, but I would add a hyphen, as you're using “B sponsored” adjectivally:

> In the upcoming Verizon-sponsored book *A tale of two cellphones*, author John Penman describes…